# Php glob function for search similliar file name

Tags: php, html, codeigniter, native

I have study case want to show image from database from folder but the name in the database is not the same as the image file name, so it's like the %like% function (like in a query).
For example the file name: 1234_abcd_0.jpg
The data in the database is only: abcd.jpg

Can php glob work if i use like this?

```
$partnameoffile="abcd";
$dirname = "media/images/";
$images = glob($dirname."*".$partnameoffile."*.png");
foreach($images as $image) { echo '<img src="'.$image.'" /><br />'; }
```

Comment: Did you try it?

Comment: just now :D , finally I got it.